# Collapse menu doesn't work in MaterializeCSS

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, materialize

I dont understand why when I click the collapse menu, nothing happens.

Can anybody tell me why ?

I think i've correctly added jQuery, everything works except the collapse menu.

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <title>Stalker - {{main.title}}</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/materialize/dist/css/materialize.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Da|Karla" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
     $( document ).ready(function){
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
     });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper  indigo darken-4">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Stalker</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li ng-hide="loggedIn"><a href="/register"><i class="tiny material-icons left">assignment_ind</i>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="loggedIn"><a href="/login"><i class="tiny material-icons left">input</i>Login</a></li>
        <li ng-show="loggedIn"><a href="/profile"><i class="tiny material-icons left">perm_identity</i>Profile</a></li>
        <li ng-show="loggedIn"><a href="/logout"><i class="tiny material-icons left">input</i>Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="dropdown-button">
        <li ng-show="loggedIn"><a href="/profile"><i class="tiny material-icons left">perm_identity</i>Profile</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="loggedIn"><a href="/register"><i class="tiny material-icons left">assignment_ind</i>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="loggedIn"><a href="/login"><i class="tiny material-icons left">input</i>Login</a></li>
        <li ng-show="loggedIn"><a href="/logout"><i class="tiny material-icons left">input</i>Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the jQuery before the script you written | and made the small change in your code for `.button-collapse`

In HTML :

```
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $( document ).ready(function(){
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
         });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the init hack, to make sure, that it is the last element initialized: http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/js/init.js

```
(function($){
    $(function(){

         $('.button-collapse').sideNav();

    }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```